# 複数の動画の1フレーム目を抜き出したい

Tags: python, opencv, 画像

あるフォルダの中の複数の動画ファイルを対象に、各動画の1フレーム目（または１～ｎ枚目）を抜き出して画像として保存したいと考えています。

動画ファイル1個であれば下記で達成しているのですが、複数個の動画ファイルに対する処理の仕方で迷っております。
基本的なことが理解できていないかもしれませんが、よろしくお願いいたします。

```
import cv2
 
video_path = "E:\UserX\Test\Trial1.mp4"
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
 
for num in range(1):　#数値を変えれば取得する画像枚数を指定可能
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, num)
    cv2.imwrite("E:\UserX\Test\picture{:0=4}".format(num)+".tif", cap.read()[1])
    print("save picture{:0=4}".format(num)+".tif")
 
cap.release()
```

Comment: 「複数個の動画ファイルに対する処理の仕方で迷っております。」とのことですが、具体的には何をどう迷われているのでしょうか？

Comment: コメントいただきありがとうございます。返信が遅くなり申し訳ありません。基本的なところなのですが、video_path = glob.glob(""E:\UserX\Test\*.mp4")のような指定で多数のmp4ファイルを一度に処理したいと考えているものの、その指定の書き方がわからない（試した限りでは動かない）というところです。お答えになっておりますでしょうか。

Comment: 「動かない」コードを掲載された方が良いのではないでしょうか？また「動かない」というのは何かエラーが発生したのか、思い通りに動かないのかどちらでしょうか？具体的に書かれると回答しやすくなるかと思います。

Answer (score 0):

下記のようにコードを書いてみました。この書き方ですと、ファイルパスのところで'/Users/~/sample' + str(i+1) + 'mp4'のように指定するようになっています。また、外に抜き出されたフレーム画像を保存するために任意のフォルダを作っておく必要があります(4行目の部分）。自分もまだ勉強中なので、うまく書けませんが参考程度になればと思います。

```
import cv2
import os # 追記

img_outdir = './img' # 追記
os.makedirs(img_outdir, exist_ok=True) # 追記
number = len(os.listdir('動画ファイルが入っているフォルダのパス')) # 追記

for i in range(number): # 追記
  movie_file = 'ファイルパス' + str(i+1) + 'ファイルの形式' # 追記
  cap = cv2.VideoCapture(movie_file)
  
  for num in range(1):　# 数値を変えれば取得する画像枚数を指定可能
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, num)
    ouimg_file = "{}/{:05d}.jpg".format(img_outdir, i+1) # 追記
    cv2.imwrite("E:\UserX\Test\picture{:0=4}".format(num)+".tif", cap.read()[1])
    print("save picture{:0=4}".format(num)+".tif")

  cap.release()
```